# Different Results from Google API and search on Google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Why do calls to the Google Maps API return different results than what I see in my browser?

This one returns hundreds of items :
https://www.google.com/maps/search/new+york+hotels/@40.7543024,-74.0025302,14z?hl=en

This one returns  Around 30 items :
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?new+york+hotels&sensor=false

Answer (score 0):

The geocoder returns postal addresses mainly.  If you want "places" (like hotels), use the places API.